# 23.10 on a NUC - not reliably waking from suspend

Tags: suspend

As the title states - I've vot 23.10 installed a NUC and I tend to put it into suspend state when I finish in the afternoon. However it is a bit hit and miss if it wakes up again.

```
wkNUC:~$ journalctl --grep='sleep|suspend|resume' --no-pager --since='-1day' 
Mar 13 15:35:16 wkNUC systemd-logind[774]: The system will suspend now!
Mar 13 15:35:16 wkNUC NetworkManager[815]: <info>  [1710315316.6826] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Mar 13 15:35:16 wkNUC NetworkManager[815]: <info>  [1710315316.6831] device (wlp6s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 13 15:35:16 wkNUC ModemManager[942]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Mar 13 15:35:16 wkNUC NetworkManager[815]: <info>  [1710315316.7374] device (p2p-dev-wlp6s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 13 15:35:16 wkNUC NetworkManager[815]: <info>  [1710315316.7452] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Mar 13 15:35:16 wkNUC NetworkManager[815]: <info>  [1710315316.7469] device (enp5s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 13 15:35:16 wkNUC NetworkManager[815]: <info>  [1710315316.8044] device (enp5s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 13 15:35:16 wkNUC NetworkManager[815]: <info>  [1710315316.9151] device (enp5s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 13 15:35:22 wkNUC systemd[1]: Reached target sleep.target - Sleep.
Mar 13 15:35:22 wkNUC systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
Mar 13 15:35:23 wkNUC systemd-sleep[73835]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Mar 13 15:35:23 wkNUC kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
-- Boot e6536061623243ac86c9582a21062335 --
Mar 14 07:01:52 wkNUC kernel: input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input0
Mar 14 07:01:52 wkNUC kernel: ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPB]
Mar 14 07:01:52 wkNUC kernel: ata1.00: Features: Dev-Sleep
Mar 14 07:01:52 wkNUC kernel: ahci 0000:00:17.0: port does not support device sleep
Mar 14 07:01:56 wkNUC systemd-logind[788]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Sleep Button)
Mar 14 07:01:58 wkNUC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1487]: (II) AMDGPU(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off
Mar 14 07:01:58 wkNUC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1487]: (II) AMDGPU(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off
Mar 14 07:01:58 wkNUC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1487]: (II) AMDGPU(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off
Mar 14 07:01:59 wkNUC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1487]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event0)
Mar 14 07:01:59 wkNUC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1487]: (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 14 07:01:59 wkNUC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1487]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
Mar 14 07:01:59 wkNUC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1487]: (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
Mar 14 07:01:59 wkNUC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1487]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Mar 14 07:01:59 wkNUC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1487]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
Mar 14 07:01:59 wkNUC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1487]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device removed
Mar 14 07:01:59 wkNUC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1487]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
Mar 14 07:01:59 wkNUC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1487]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Mar 14 07:01:59 wkNUC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1487]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
```

It appears to detect the buttons, but never appears to actually wake up.

Any ideas?